Garage door not closing when sunlight is bright
My garage door with an old Wayne Dalton opener will not close when sunlight is bright, unless I keep the wall button pressed. This means that I cannot close the garage door using a remote when it's sunny.
The door works fine when it's overcast, so the problem is not alignment of or dirt on the sensors. Putting shade around the sensors does not help.
The only thing that helps is laying down some flat, dark objects on the ground between the sensors as shown in the attached pic below to absorb the sunlight falling on the concrete floor between the sensors.
Has anyone had this issue before? What was the solution?
There are 2 solutions I'm looking at:

Paint the concrete between the sensors using a dark, weather-proof paint
Replace the sensors with new ones

Any advice? If I try solution 2, will swapping out the old sensors for new ones create compatibility issues with my old opener?
Thanks.


Try adding a short tube to the receiver to help it reject ambient light. A flat black interior will help absorb off-axis light.

Thanks for the comment @HABO. I tried share around both transmitter and receiver (see my original post) which didn't help. It wasn't a tube - it was a cardboard box. But the black paint shows promise.

take a toilet paper tube

@HABO I tried toilet paper tubes instead of cardboard boxes and that seems to work. See my detailed comment in the accepted solution. Thanks to you and Traveler as well!

You can buy purpose-made tubes for a few bucks.  They are already black, they are not made of cardboard, and they screw securely onto the sensor frame.   If it works it will last longer than a toilet paper roll.
You can try swapping the two sensors. If the problem is coming from the sun when it is in one particular direction that might fix it.
You can try cleaning the transmitter and receiver.  The sun isn't blocking the sensor, it's overwhelming it.  If the normal signal is blocked by dirt or webs, the problem is more likely to occur.

I have a similar situation, when the sun is coming up, for a short time, it shines practically into the sensor lense and cause the same issue, only in the morning when the sun is at a certain position. I use a trash can for the few times it occurs. It throws a long shadow and stops the sunlight from doing its thing. I think your tube fix is the way to go.

Attaching toilet paper tubes (instead of cardboard box I tried before) to the sensors using some tape is working! I wrapped some black electrical tape around the tube to make them more weatherproof also. I guess that cardboard boxes I had were too wide and it really needed some narrow tubing.

Just FYI, as other have said, placing the sensor inside a tube blocks the sunlight and allows the opposite sensor to see the beam.
What worked best for me was a short piece of gutter downspout lined up with the Sensor inside to block the sunlight.

